# Revolution slider don't shows all slides

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I have Revolution Slider's based wordpress galleries.

[example slider](http://www.aldenatemp.altervista.org/progetti/frn-serramenti-casa-moderna-risparmio-energetico-design/)

Sliders with few slides, like up to 10 images works perfectly, but  when the gallery has more images (more than 10) these are shown to be active referring to the bullet counts, but they don't show up. Only the first 10 slides are shown.

this is a screenshot of the problem http://prnt.sc/awxz76

Any idea how solve this?

Comment: Its your blog posts per page setting in Settings ->  Reading

Comment: same images are repeated

Comment: Setting of max post per page solved the issue.Thank you very much